# Custom ListView updating only last value android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

It might be silly question, but I am having bit hard time to make it work.

I have a custom list view adapter which some textview and imageview. 
But when I am updating listview using custom adapter it is only updating last value. here is my code

Adapter code

```
public class InfoListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<aSProperty> {

Context mContext;
List<aSProperty> values= null;

 public InfoListAdapter(Context mContext,  List<aSProperty> data) {

   super(mContext, R.layout.list_row, data);
   this.mContext = mContext;
   this.values = data.;
 }

 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
       signal = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.images);
       type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
       info = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.info);
       image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc);
           Log.d(TAG, "List Size"+values.size());
           for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
               Log.d(TAG, "DATA"+values.get(i).type);
               type.setText(values.get(i).type);
           }

   }
 ImageView image;
     TextView type;
      TextView info;
   static String TAG= "InfoListAdapter";


   return convertView;
```

}

```
}
```

Code to populate adapter

```
  info_panel = new InfoListAdapter(esActivity.this, allData);
            list.setAdapter(info_panel);
```

But I do not know why, it is only showing last values from values list. In addition I want to change image based on condition and data inside values, any good way to do this.

Comment: Use `ViewHolder` pattern for better performance.

Comment: Ok Thanks, but why it only updating last value in textview

Comment: This is because your view is recycled. Thats why need to use viewholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use following code



public class InfoListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<aSProperty> {

Context mContext;
List<aSProperty> values= null;

 public InfoListAdapter(Context mContext,  List<aSProperty> data) {

   super(mContext, R.layout.list_row, data);
   this.mContext = mContext;
   this.values = data.;
 }

 @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
       signal = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.images);
       type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
       info = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.info);
       image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc);
           Log.d(TAG, "List Size"+values.size());

               type.setText(values.get(position).type);


   }
 ImageView image;
     TextView type;
      TextView info;
   static String TAG= "InfoListAdapter";


   return convertView;

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks it was position issue .this line  type.setText(values.get(position).type);..:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to override getCount() method of your adapter like this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return values .size();
}
```

and then in your getView() method you have to do something like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mycartslistcontents,
                null);
        holder.yourImageView= (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.yourTextView= (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textview);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    // here set your textView text and image resource


    return convertView;
}
```

Don't forget to take a global variable layoutInflater at the top like this

```
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
```

and initialise it in your constructor this way

```
layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(yourContext);
```

and here is your ViewHolder class

```
static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView yourImageView;
    TextView yourTextView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still it is the same, I followed exactly the same